# Send app to background on button tap

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

In my apps there is a button named "Back". When the user clicks on that button, the apps should be sent to the background, like when we click on the home button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you manage to do this, it is against Apple's HIG (because it will look as a crash to the user) - if you plan to publish your app on the AppStore you'll be rejected.

Answer (score 1):

I think turning to background is impossible.

Make user press home button by using UIAlertView with no cancel button.

Comment: and then what? app comes back up with the same alert, if 'app does not run in background' set to NO, which is true for most of them.

Answer (score 1):

We can send an application to the background using SpringBoardUI or the SpringBoardServices private frameworks.

However, Apple won't accept this on the App Store.